# UINavigationController Offset

Tags: iphone, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController which appears at an offset of 20px.
This is the exact problem I'm having:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=761616
But I can't seem to figure out what the right way to solve it is.

Thanks,

Comment: How are you adding the UINav view to the screen?

Comment: I initialize it, push a viewController into it and add it's view to the main view...

Comment: Same issue here. iOS 4.3.1 in combination wth a UISplitViewController. Have tried everything, no success. Even setting the frame does not help.

Answer (score 2):

After I searched the possible way to solve, people said it should be shifted by 20 pixels programmatically.
Here is my solution:

```
// adjust the frame of subview which is going to be add
self.navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
[self.view addSubView:self.navController.view];
```

It works fine for me now, good luck~ :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is setting splitviewcontroller's frame to `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];`
e.g

```
self.mSplitViewC.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the frame is set at (0,0). It probably has that space because you add 20px to the Y position to make up for the status bar, but that is already handled for us.

Comment: I didn't touch the frame. It's supposed to be aligned to 0,0 automatically.
Plus, if I do try to manually adjust the frame, then I can see the offset and only a second of two after that, it pops into place.

Comment: Did you try changing the frame in the "viewWillAppear:" method? And are you sure you haven't touched the frame in any of your code or xibs?

Comment: Yes, I aven't touched the frame anywhere (not in the nib and not in the code). Plus, I just opened a new project, did the same thing and the offset was still there. And, when I hide the status bar the navigation bar appear on the top of the screen (40 px higher than it is now). I think I'm missing something here...

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a status bar as your top bar from Interface Builder?. May be you have kept space for status bar.

Comment: No. I haven't touched the interface builder. I've added the navigation controller programmatically.

Comment: I think its best to hide the status bar from the info.plist.There's a entry called "Status bar is initially hidden" in the plist. Tick that entry and remove your status bar hiding code from your project.